# Why does Rare characters appears when json file is uploaded to azure blob storage c#?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am trying to update a JSON file which is located in azure blob storage. when the program does the put call the saved file looks like this:

> Zona de especial protecci\u00F3n

the accents and other characters are the matter, but that only happens when I download the file from the azure UI interface if I do a get from postman, that does not happen. this is my code:

```
SemanticDictionaryContent semanticDictionaryContent = new SemanticDictionaryContent()
        {
            Name = entity.Id + JSON_EXTENSION,
            Content = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(entity)

        };
```

Comment: Is the file you downloaded UTF8?

Comment: @nilsK this page is UTF8. UTF8 isn't an escape sequence, it's used to *avoid* escape sequences for non US-ASCII characters. That's why I can write `Αυτό Εδώ` without problem or resorting to escape sequences

Comment: `only happens when I download the file from the azure UI interface` in that case this isn't a programming issue at all. `\u00F3` is the escape sequence for ó. For some reason the Azure UI produced a valid JSON file where non-US-ASCII characters are replaced by their equivalent and equally valid escape sequences. Any JSON parser will deserialize the escape sequence to `ó`.

Comment: it is fixed with the next line: Content = new BinaryData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity))) but I don´t know

Comment: "the accents and other characters are the matter" - in what way is it a "matter" at all? That's perfectly valid JSON - I don't think you should be worried by this. After all, there are other things that absolutely *have* to be escaped, such as backslashes. If you're not bothered by that, what's the problem with U+00F3 being escaped?

Comment: the problem is when I want to download the json file from azure, I don't have the document with scaped characters. another choice I´ve seen is this:

Comment: var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping };

 

            SemanticDictionaryContent semanticDictionaryContent = new SemanticDictionaryContent()
            {
                Name = entity.Id + JSON_EXTENSION,
                Content = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(entity, options)
            };
            contentRepository.Update(semanticDictionaryContent);

Comment: try using `CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");  
container.CreateIfNotExists();    
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myjsonfile.json");    
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\myjsonfile.json"));  
Console.WriteLine("Blob URI: " + blockBlob.Uri);`

Comment: reading from de blob by code or postman is no problem, the problem appears when the download is done by azure UI.

Comment: For updating json file , try it `CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myjsonfile.json"); 
string jsonString = blob.DownloadText(); 
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
json.name = "New name"; 
blob.UploadText(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a storage account in azure.

[image]

2. Create a container in azure.

[image]

3. Uploaded a `Json` file to a container using the below code.

> I have used the below approach in Uploading / downloading / editing the Json file.

```
 public static bool Upload()
        {
            try
            {
            var containerName = "mycontainer";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionSting);
            CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
                
            var isCreated = container.CreateIfNotExists();
            container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@"C:\Tools\local.settings.json", FileMode.Open))
             {
               using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                   memoryStream.Position = 0;
                   fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                   var fileName  = "local.settings.json";
                   CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                   string mimeType = "application/unknown";
                   string ext = (fileName.Contains(".")) ? System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower() : "." + fileName;
                   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
                   if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null) mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
                   memoryStream.ToArray();
                   memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                   blob.Properties.ContentType = mimeType;
                   blob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Uploaded `Json` file
[image]

4. Updated the Json file in azure and uploaded it using the below code.

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionSting);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
            CloudBlockBlob jsonBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("local.settings.json");
            string jsonText = jsonBlob.DownloadText();

            dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText);
            jsonData.property1 = "Property1";
            jsonData.property2 = "Property2";
            jsonBlob.UploadText(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData));
```

5. And downloaded the Json file from azure manually and do not find any special characters.

[image]

Comment: But did you try to use accented characters, like in `Zona de especial protección`?

Comment: Yes, I did for that also. And I do not see any rare characters in Json file. You can check this [Image](https://i.imgur.com/YUau1Is.png)